# In search of a connector for EL panels

Tags: connector

I have  the [EL Sequencer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12781) from  Sparkfun which  uses JST PH connectors on the DC and the AC side, but my EL panels all  have [JST SM](https://www.pcboard.ca/image/cache/catalog/products/connectors/jst/jst-sm-2pin/JST-SM-2-Pin-Connector-Set-Male-Female-Open-600x315.jpg) connectors. There seems  to be enough  space to solder more connectors on the  underside of the sequencer (although barely) or  I could  even  desolder the PH ones (which are somewhat out-of-spec anyway, as they are rated only up to 50V and EL works with  3x to 6x the voltage).
The question  only remains, which  connectors  to use instead?

My initial idea was to use JST XH  on the board to plug an "extension cable" (maybe sub 1 meter) and use an 8-10 pin connector  on the  other end.
Or should  I  forego the board-to-wire connectors and solder short wires to the board and equip them with wire-to-wire, like  JST SM? (The more I think about it the  more it seems like  the better idea)

I say 8 or 10 pin connector because all the panels end up close to each other (in a pattern) and I want them to be disconnectable in a single action.

My question: Are  there other recommendable connectors that can be used as  wire-to-wire AND  as wire-to-board? I find JST's self-incompatibility on this front annoying.
Are there any faults in my thinking?

Comment: Please rephrase the question so it doesn't look like a shopping question: https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/ but looks like a technical question.

Answer (score 1):

The EL wire system runs up to 120V, per [IPC specs](http://www.smpspowersupply.com/ipc2221pcbclearance.html) an 0.2mm or 8mil clearance should be used between traces and connector pads on the PCB with 120V (150V). In addition, 16mil should be used between coated insulation on wires.

This means any connector could be used that has an 8mil clearance between the connectors.

I like molex and JST connectors, if I am looking for a new connector the digikey paper catalog is makes it easy to compare connectors and connectors are listed by product family.